# implement has_many through association in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, has-many-through

I am working with has_many :through association in Application. I implement association between models like :-

in `employee.rb`

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :inventories, through: :employee_inventories
end
```

in `inventory.rb`

```
class Inventory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees, through: :employee_inventories
end
```

in `employee_inventories.rb`

```
class EmployeeInventory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :inventory
end
```

I create a method in InventoryController.rb like:

```
    def inventory_status
      p 'paramsssssssssssssssssssssssssssss'
      p params
      p employee_inventories_params
      @employee_inventories = @inventory.employee_inventories.build(employee_inventories_params)
      if @employee_inventories.save
      p 'sssssssssssssssssssssssssss'
      redirect_to inventories_path
      else
      p 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
      render :action => :show
   end

     def employee_inventories_params
        params.require(:employee_inventory).permit(:employee_id, :status)
      end
```

and in view of my application I render this method by this

```
<%= link_to 'Request for inventory', inventory_status_inventory_path(@inventory),
:class => 'btn btn-success' %>
```

when I run this this gives me error

> ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is
>   empty: employee_inventory)

I want to store employee_id and status in employee_inventory table. please guide me. How to implement? Thankz in advance.

Comment: What is the output of you logging 'params' and 'employee_inventories_params'?

Comment: from params i got 
{"controller"=>"inventories", "action"=>"inventory_status", "id"=>"1"}
and employee_inventory_params i got 'params is missing'

Comment: It's because your link_to is a 'get' request, you're not actually posting any data to it all so no 'employee_inventory' key exists in params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code

```
 def inventory_status
      @employee_inventories = EmployeeInventory.new(employee_inventories_params)
      if @employee_inventories.save
       redirect_to inventories_path
      else
       render :action => :show
      end
   end
```

and in your view

```
 <%= link_to 'Request for inventory', inventory_status_inventory_path(@inventory, employee_inventory => {:employee_id => 1, :status => 'test'}),
:class => 'btn btn-success' %>
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: This is the right answer but this approach (from the original question, not the answer itself) is not RESTful. You should be creating in a 'create' action of the relevant controller via post really.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, there is no data matched with key `employee_inventory` in `def employee_inventories_params` thus you are getting this error.

You can `inspect` `params` for track what it sending to your controller. In you form params you should get something like following

```
:employee_inventory => {:employee_id => 1, :status => true}
```